# How to get row id from row Index in table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose this is my table:

```
<table>
    <tr id="a">
       <TD>a</TD>
    </tr>
    <tr id="b">
       <TD>b</TD>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I get row id using the row index from a table?

Above is just an example where id is static but in my case my id is dynamic, so I can't use
`document.getElementById()`.

Comment: even with dynamic ID's, it should still work.

Comment: `table.tr[1].id` -> `b`?

Comment: @MarcB it should be `table.rows` not `table.tr`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you have only one table on your page:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[index].id;
```

**Preferably** though, you'd give your `table` a `id`, though, and get your row like this:

```
<table id="tableId">
    <tr id="a">
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="b">
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
var row = table.rows[index];
console.log(row.id);
```

This way, you can be certain you don't get any interference, if you have multiple tables in your page.

Answer (score 4):

> *"So, How can i get row id using row Index from a table"*

You would select the `table`, and use the `.rows` property to get the row by index.

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]; // first table

var secondRow = table.rows[1]; // second row
```

---

Then you just get the ID in the typical manner.

```
console.log(secondRow.id); // "b"
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/MErPk/

Answer (score 2):

**Answer has been edited**
With CSS3 you can use the **nth-child** selctor. Here the example shows the rowIndex = 2

```
 alert(document.querySelector("table tr:nth-child(2)").id);
```

In jQuery you can do this with

```
 alert($("table tr:nth-child(2)").attr('id'));
```

The same syntax **nth-child()** can be used in CSS

```
<style>
    tr:nth-child(2) {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Why use jQuery on something as simple as getting a table row?

Comment: Just an example to show how nth-child (also a CSS selector) works.

Comment: Fair enough, but you might want to mention [how horribly slow jQuery is](http://jsperf.com/table-row-native-vs-jquery) on things like this.

Comment: ya i know it work using jquery bt i dnt want use that.Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: Yes, jQuery is slow at this. And you dont want to load it just for there simple things.

Comment: You can demonstrate Selectors API based DOM selection without using jQuery. Use `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: You're welcome, and FYI, it's supported in IE8 and up as well as Firefox, Chrome, etc, so it covers around 98% of browsers in use.