# Record is not updated

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax

I send data through Ajax to update.aspx page along with the id. I don't know whether it is correct or not.

I checked the data, and it is not sent to the update.aspx page.The form consists of `fname,age` fields only. This is the way I send the data to update.aspx for update when the user clicks the edit button:

```
data: {fname: '" + $('#fname').val() + "',age: '" + $('#age').val() + "'}" + "&id=" + id,
```

Screen shot image.

[image]

**Ajax full code**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST';,
    url: 'update.aspx/doSomething',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { fname: '" + $('#fname').val() + "', age: '" + $('#age').val() + "'}" + "& id=" + id, 
                    success: function(data) {
    }
```

**update.aspx page**

```
public class UserClass
{
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public static string doSomething(string fname, int age, int id)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.; Initial Catalog = jds; Integrated Security= true;");
    string sql = "update record set name ='" + fname + "', age ='" + age + "' where id = '" + id + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    return "Sucess";
}
```

**when i click edit button it goes to the function get_category_details along with record id** 
Edit button code

```
"sTitle": "Edit",
"mData": "id",
"render": function (mData, type, row, meta) {
       return '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick="get_category_details(' + mData + ')  ">Edit</button>';
```

**get_category_details** all data displayed in the textboxs.

```
  function get_category_details(id) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'edit_return.asmx/doSome',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: "{id: '" + id + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                        isNew = false;                    
                       id = data.d[0].id
                       $('#fname').attr('value', data.d[0].fname);
                       $('#age').attr('value', data.d[0].age);

                    }
                });
            }
```

**this id varable i used to send for update
id = data.d[0].id**

Comment: **[LITTLE BOBBY TABLES ALERT](http://bobby-tables.com)**

Comment: @VaibhavBhavsar Please [stop adding tags to the question's title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/133056).

Answer (score 0):

change your ajax code as below

```
 var dataValue = { "fname": $('#fname').val(), "age": $('#age').val(), "id": id};

         $.ajax({                  
                            type:'POST';,
                            url: 'update.aspx/doSomething',
                            dataType: 'JSON',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            data: JSON.stringify(dataValue),
                            success: function (data) {

                            }
              });
```

change your webmethod code as below

```
public class UserClass
{
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public int? id { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public static string doSomething(UserClass userClass)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.; Initial Catalog = jds; Integrated Security= true;");
    string sql = "update record set name ='" + userClass.fname + "', age ='" + userClass.age + "' where id = '" + userClass.id + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    return "Sucess";
}
```

Comment: Can you explain _why_ he should change and _what_ your code does different?

Comment: that was a syntax error on the data : section . you misplaced }.

Comment: if i write like this getting error sir    data: {fname: '" + $('#fname').val() + "',age: '" + $('#age').val() + "', id: youridVariable},               expected ;

Comment: change youridVariable with the Id value you have

Comment: data: {fname: '" + $('#fname').val() + "',age: '" + $('#age').val() + "', id: id}, like this but error sir    expected  ;

Comment: I have modified the answer..pls try

Comment: you missed   }); at the ajax closing end

Comment: now there were no error but records not updated data not passing to the page

Comment: have you tried the latest code i have written on the answer ? put a debugger in ur web method and check whether the ajax call hits ur webmethod or not

Comment: sir i tried put the break point but no data passed is there any error i updated the full codes above

Comment: id = data.d[0].id this the id variable. update.aspx correct or not sir

Comment: i tried the code which you posted now. but record didn't updated sir.

Comment: try Console.log(dataValue) and check the value is correct or not

Comment: which place do i have to call it  Console.log(dataValue) inside the ajax success function

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined  this line error var dataValue = { "fname": $('#fname').val(), "age": $('#age').val(), "id": id};

Comment: it is because the id is not declared anywhere on the page. declare id and assign correct value to it and try

Comment: hardcode  "id":0  in the datavalue and check it hits or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185865/discussion-between-midhun-p-and-programmer-hari).

Answer (score 0):

You can update only your ajx function like that

```
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'update.aspx/doSomething',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {
               fname:$('#fname').val(),
               age:$('#age').val(),
               id:id //this id is your like fname or age that.You have get id from your request
      } 
      success: function(data) {
     }
```

Comment: {fname: 'kobianth',age: '122', id: 'null'} pass like that sir

Comment: _data = "{fname: '" + $('#fname').val() + "',age: '" + $('#age').val() + "', id: '" + id + "'}"; this how i sent the values in to update.aspx page id always getting null

Comment: First you get id from selected row Like This 
      
var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
var row = table.rows[index];
console.log(row.id);//this is your id values
    alert($("table tr:nth-child(2)").attr('id'));
     reference Get id from Table :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746153/how-to-get-row-id-from-row-index-in-table-using-javascript